# Unity of work used with more database

Tags: database, design-patterns, unit-of-work

I am learning some patterns, Unity of work / repository... There are some examples on web, but no one connects to more than one database.

In my applications almost always I have the need to get some object from a database (for example users) and some other object from another, how can I use the patterns ? (Since I am a novice on this subject an explicit example is a must)

Thank you!

Comment: There is something that can I add to increase the chances of a response? The question is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

As a general reference I advise you and anyone interested to visit http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html
which has a collection of UML and explanation over the most common Design Pattern for enterprises software
In your specific case **Unity of work** is particularly suited to work along with **Data Mapper** and **Identity Map**. I guess to understand 100% unity of work one must master also the other 2 pattern.

To answer your question I think you can create a unity of work and save it in a registry, so it is available all over the application. The unity must be a singleton since you need to ensure a central gateway to communicate with the database. Inside your unity of work you will have an identity map which is a collection of valued Objects in memory representing your model which is responsible to maintain the object states during all the application's operations. The unity will be used by your service layer to perform CRUD operations over the model and commit these changes.
To work with more databases I guess you need to leverage some sort of namespaced access to the object stored in the Identity map. You have the choice where to namespace: unity of work or identity map. The decision is really up to your application and use cases. You might need to connect to different DBs for splitting responsibilities between read and write or trying to integrate heterogeneous data sources.
An alternative would be to inject the DB object into the unity of work methods, in this case the application has 100% control over which database is used.

The **repository** pattern as far as I understand helps you to abstract to the storage of you model and it is particularly useful when you are working with heterogeneous data sources of you must provide such a flexibility to your application. Therefore I guess it is quite different from unity of work and Data Mapper layer.